# Switching Power Supply Issues

Tags: switching-regulator

The below picture is the power supply part of a board from a vendor. We keep having issues where the PIC being powered by it will randomly go back into bootloader. While we don't know for sure we suspect an issue with this power supply. We also have to replace D1 from time to time. One board was missing D1 and instead had a solder bridge, now U2 is blown up. The input power is from and array of 4 12volt AGM batteries. While charging we see voltages as high as 58V. Recently a 48VDC-48VDC external power supply was added to keep the input to this board more steady and to get rid of some noise on the line.

From looking at this schematic is there any obvious issues I should look into?

[image: Switching Power Supply]

Comment: Probably insufficient decoupling. Show layout. Show oscillograms of Vin and Lx.

Comment: A '4148 for input polarity protection? No idea what C3 is, but that feels optimistic, it has a non repetative surge rating of an amp give or take, with C3 discharged and connected to 50 odd volts thru 10 ohms, I make the surge 5A. Try a 1N4001 instead, much more robust. C6 is minimum value for that LDO, read the datasheet on this cap, especially if you have used a ceramic, but note the ESR limits anyway, an unstable reg will cause all sorts of pain. Speaking of which C7 is probably important to the switcher stability, check the datasheet there as well.

Comment: To improve even further, replace D1 with the body diode of a power FET (P-channel) and connect the gate to ground.  Reverse protection without the diode drop.  If you have trouble finding a cheap FET with a max Vgs over 60V, use a resistive divider or zener to limit Vgs.